# How to get elements which have no children, but may have text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the [empty selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/empty) says that: Matches all elements that have no children (including text nodes).
Finds all elements that are empty - they don't have child elements or text.
What i want is to get elements which has no children but may have text inside., how?

**UPDATE:**
Example:
I want select these elements which has no children but may have text, with syntax like this:

```
$('div:empty, a:empty, span, p:empty, td:empty, img, input').mousemove(myMouseOverHandler);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Get any element that doesn't have any other element:

```
$('*:not(:has(*))');
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that this does not work the other way around: "*:has(:not(*))" fails for some internal reason.

Comment: Makes some sense if you think about how a CSS selector engine might possibly be going about trying to interpret selectors. `has` shouldn't need to be aware of how to handle `not`. Better yet, what the hell would `not(*)` even mean? How would it translate to what we want? At any rate, this answer is awesome because it saved my bacon.

Comment: Is there a similar CSS selector for this?

Answer (score 19):

If an element has only text, [`children()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children) will have a length of `0`:

```
<div id="test1">
Hello World
</div>

<div id="test2">
<b>Hey there</b>
</div>

<script>
alert($("#test1").children().length); // alerts 0
alert($("#test2").children().length); // alerts 1 (the bold tag)
</script>
```

**EDIT**: In response to your edit, jQuery is awesome enough to let you do custom filters:

```
$.expr[':'].emptyOrText = function(e) {  
    return $(e).children().length == 0;
};
```

So, using the above against the HTML above, you could do this:

```
$('div:emptyOrText'); // will select #test1
```

Comment: I guess he is looking for something like an ":only-text" selector. The children() method only helps if you have the id.

Comment: Nice touch with the custom selector! No need to use the 'extend' method though - just do jQuery.expr[':].emptyOrText = function(){...}

Comment: Also, 0 converts to false and trying to access [0] is shorter than 'length' - ... So you can just do 'return !$(e).children()[0]'

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure on the syntax for custom selectors, that is shorter. Thanks. As far as the length, I kind of like it with length as it reads better and someone coming across it later can make sense of it a little easier, I think.

Comment: nice answer, Paolo...this extends beyond the current question. I know I will return to this to solve future problems.

Answer (score 6):

I made a pure JavaScript function for anyone that does not want to use jQuery.

```
const getElementsWithNoChildren = (target) => {
    let candidates;

    if (target && typeof target.querySelectorAll === 'function') {
        candidates = target.querySelectorAll('*');
    }
    else if (target && typeof target.length === 'number') {
        candidates = target;
    }
    else {
        candidates = document.querySelectorAll('*');
    }

    return Array.from(candidates).filter((elem) => {
        return elem.children.length === 0;
    });
};
```