# jquery :empty but ignoring text nodes

Tags: jquery

say my markup is:

```
<ul>
    <li id="num1">hello</li>
    <li id="num2"><p>hello</p></li>
    <li id="num3">sdf dfg</li>
    <li id="num4"></li>
    <li id="num5"><a>linky</a></li>
</ul>
```

how do I query the `ul` to return `#num1, #num3 and #num4` (the ones with no child tags)?

something like:

```
$('ul').children('li:empty')
```

however from the docs:

```
:empty  Returns: Array<Element(s)>
Matches all elements that have no children (including text nodes).
```

because it includes text, the above query is only returning me `#num4`.

What should/can I do instead?

Edit: I'm also using jQuery 1.1.4 (don't ask)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to get elements which have no children, but may have text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743957/how-to-get-elements-which-have-no-children-but-may-have-text)

Comment: ah my bad, this is duplicate then

Comment: Ah. I looked for the link to that question before giving up and just posting what the answer was on here. I still don't quite think the :not(:has(*)) is very... elegant, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('ul').children().filter(function()
{
    return $(this).children().length != 0;
});
```

Basically, the function checks if the number of immediate children is zero. It might not be the most elegant solution but at least it will work.